# Open RStudio help in viewer instead of browser

Tags: rstudio

When accessing help in RStudio, the following error message is printed and a browser is opened.

```
help(glmnet) 
Error in as.character(tools:::httpdPort) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' 
Error in as.character(tools:::httpdPort) :
...
```

How do I get Rstudio to open it in the viewer?

Comment: This question appears to have the same *answer* as the other question (= upgrade your Rstudio), but it is not obviously the same question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Needs to be updated to Version 0.98.1103 (assuming you are using Yosemite OS X). The problem resolved for me as soon as I did.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and indeed my version was not up to date... updated and it works now. Thanks! But it seems like there are no repositories for available for Rstudio on Ubuntu?