# Dygraphs error cannot coerce type closure to vector of type character

Tags: r, dygraphs

when trying to use the Dygraphs package, I keep getting the following error:

```
"Error in as.character(tools:::httpdPort) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"
```

This happens even when I try and plot the Dygraphs example:

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths)
```

I currently use the latest version of R (R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)), so cannot understand why I keep getting this message? Any ideas?

Comment: works fine for me - have you redefined one of your variables to a function? Try restarting R.

Comment: Nope, I still get the same error. Can't understand why?!

Comment: Hello Nick, the example works well in the R console. Have you tried updating your RStudio version? There are issues with some specific version similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782921/open-rstudio-help-in-viewer-instead-of-browser